# JavaScript operator similar to SQL "like"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulating SQL LIKE in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314045/emulating-sql-like-in-javascript)

Is there an operator in JavaScript which is similar to the `like` operator in SQL? Explanations and examples are appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314045/emulating-sql-like-in-javascript

Answer (score 101):

You can use [regular expressions in Javascript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) to do pattern matching of strings.

For example:

```
var s = "hello world!";
if (s.match(/hello.*/)) {
  // do something
}
```

The `match()` test is much like `WHERE s LIKE 'hello%'` in SQL.

Comment: It's better to use `test` here (which should, by the way, be faster), since actual match result is not needed.

Comment: Most definitely, use `/regex/.test(s)` here, unless you want to do something with the matches - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/1128978

Answer (score 41):

No.

You want to use: `.indexOf("foo")` and then check the index. If it's >= 0, it contains that string.

Comment: If the case is different, it will not work. You need to use: `myString.toLowerCase().indexOf("foo")`

Comment: On **integers** use `toString()` first. `myInteger.toString().indexOf(value) > -1`.

Answer (score 29):

Use the string objects Match method:

```
// Match a string that ends with abc, similar to LIKE '%abc'
if (theString.match(/^.*abc$/)) 
{ 
    /*Match found */
}

// Match a string that starts with abc, similar to LIKE 'abc%'
if (theString.match(/^abc.*$/)) 
{ 
    /*Match found */
}
```

Comment: how to match a string based on substring, for e.g if str="john edward"
then how can I use the function to return true in both cases, like if str contains john => true , if str contains edward => should return true too.

Comment: Thanks. its very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You can check the [`String.match`()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) or the [`String.indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp) methods.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't, but you can check out [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) as a starting point to developing your own, and/or look into [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It would be a good idea to familiarise yourself with the [JavaScript string functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

EDIT: This has been answered before:

[Emulating SQL LIKE in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314045/emulating-sql-like-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

No, there isn't any.

The list of comparison operators are listed here.

[Comparison Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_comparisons.asp)

For your requirement the best option would be [regular expressions](http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm).

Comment: Please provide some quality code with examples, rather than short yes or no answers, avoiding links that can be offline in the future.