# Javascript match similar to sql like operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want do all the operation of sql 'like' in javascript. for example:

```
var str="South-Asia, North-America, South-Africa";

var firstwordmatch=South%; //will result South-Asia,South-Africa
var last match=%ica // will match North-America, South-Africa
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
var ex = str.split('%')[1]; // this for matching %ica

var l = str.length;
var n = str.indexOf("%");
// this for matching %ica
if (n == 0) {                   
    var m = c.match(/(.*)ex/)
}
// this for matching 
// this for matching south%
else if (n == l - 1) {
    var m = c.match(/ex(.*)/)
}
```

but I am unable to write the correct regular expression because it does not get the ex variable.

Comment: this link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315224/javascript-operator-similar-to-sql-like

Answer (score 0):

**Starts with South: `South\S+`**

In JS:

```
var myregex = /South\S+/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[0];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```

**Ends with ica: `\S+ica`**

In JS:

```
var myregex = /\S+ica/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[0];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```

**Explanation**

- `\S+` matches any chars that are not white-space characters
- `South` matches literal chars
- `ica` matches literal chars