# BIRT computed column use operator LIKE

Tags: eclipse, report, reporting, birt

How to use operator like in BIRT computed column?

I tried:

```
if (row["Dept"] == "%desc%") { 'Test1' } else  { 'Test2' }
```

but it doesn't work.

And

```
if (row["Dept"] like "%desc%") { 'Test1' } else  { 'Test2' }
```

I have an error message - `[Row:1, Column:28] missing ) after condition`

---

For example in Crystal Reports I use

```
if {Dept} like ["*desc*", "*desc1*"] then 'Test1' else 'Test2'
```

But BIRT not support operator 'then'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` is SQL syntax, whereas the expression syntax for a computed column is Javascript. But why are you using a computed column at all, when you can achieve the same result with pure SQL? E.g. with Oracle, the following SQL expression is equivalent:

```
case
when DEPT like '%desc%' then 'Test1'
else 'Test2'
end
```

OTOH if you insist on using a computed column, you could use regular expressions. See [JavaScript operator similar to SQL "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315224/javascript-operator-similar-to-sql-like)