# Javascript "Like" and "*" expression Eqv from VBA

Tags: javascript

i recently started working with Javascript coming from VBA i would like to know if there is an equivalent to vba's "like" and "*" expressions.

Example:

```
If test Like "01##############10*" Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for *regular expressions*. For instance, if `#` means "digit" and `*` means "anything" in your example, the regex would be `/^01\d{13}10/`, e.g.:

```
if (/^01\d{13}10/.test(test)) {
```

Which says:

- `^` - Match start of string ("start assertion" or "start anchor")
- `01` - Match `01` literally
- `\d{13}` - Match a digit (`\d`) exactly 13 times
- `10` - Match `10` literally

The absense of a `$` anchor means we don't care what follows after the above.

Regular expressions are objects with methods. One of those methods, [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), checks to see if a string matches the expression, one of the most basic operations available. There's also [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (find the first/next match). Coming at it from the other side, strings also have a [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method which accepts a regular expression and looks for matches within the string.

More on regex:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [SO Regular Expression FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Thanks for the quick Help !

Comment: Also check https://regex101.com/. Huge library of expressions and a quick way to test your own.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has RegEx.
With RegEx you can try to build anything like "Like" or "*".

In general - unfortunately anything that is available in VBA is available in the other top languages. The vice versa is not always the case.

This is how to search for `vi*`:

```
var myStr = "vityata";
if (myStr.match(/vi.*/)) {
  // your code here
}
```

A little more here:
[Emulating SQL LIKE in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314045/emulating-sql-like-in-javascript)